# taglib : how to edit Album Artist?

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, taglib, id3

How to modify the "Album Artist" field of a MP3 file with the library TagLib ?
Is there something similar to :

```
f.tag()->setArtist("blabla");
```

?

Comment: I don't understand the difference between TagLib::FileRef and TagLib::File. If I use TagLib::FileRef f("foo.mp3");, I cannot use f.tag().removeFrames. If I use TagLib::MPEG::File f("foo.mp3");, I should be able to use f.ID3v2Tag()->removeFrames What's the difference between TagLib::FileRef and TagLib::File?

Comment: `FileRef` is just a convenience class that handles instantiating the appropriate `TagLib::File` subclass for the file format -- i.e. it'll work whether you throw and Ogg, FLAC, or MP3 file at it.  There's no standard for "Album Artist", though, so you have to drop down to a less generic abstraction, which is where `MPEG::File` comes in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID3v2 doesn't actually support a field called "album artist".  iTunes uses the TPE2 frame, which is supposed to be:

> TPE2
>   The 'Band/Orchestra/Accompaniment' frame is used for additional information about the performers in the recording.

For a complete list of frames see http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Declared_ID3v2_frames.

To write that with TagLib, this would do the trick:

```
#include <mpegfile.h>
#include <id3v2tag.h>
#include <textidentificationframe.h>

int main()
{
    TagLib::MPEG::File file("foo.mp3");
    TagLib::ByteVector handle = "TPE2";
    TagLib::String value = "bar";
    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *tag = file.ID3v2Tag(true);

    if(!tag->frameList(handle).isEmpty())
    {
        tag->frameList(handle).front()->setText(value);
    }
    else
    {
        TagLib::ID3v2::TextIdentificationFrame *frame =
            new TagLib::ID3v2::TextIdentificationFrame(handle, TagLib::String::UTF8);
        tag->addFrame(frame);
        frame->setText(value);
    }

    file.save();

    return 0;
}
```

If you just want to remove the frames, you can simply do:

```
TagLib::MPEG::File file("foo.mp3");
TagLib::ID3v2::Tag *tag = file.ID3v2Tag();

if(tag)
{
    tag->removeFrames("TPE2");
    file.save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I just wanted to delete the "Album Artist" field. (sorry my question was not precise). Is there a shorter way to delete this "Album Artist" tag ? Is it better to a) remove the field  or b) `setText("")`  ?

Comment: `removeFrames` doesn't seem to work with `TagLib::Tag` :

http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1Tag.html

Comment: You need to use `TagLib::ID3v2::Tag`, as I did in my example: http://taglib.github.io/api/classTagLib_1_1ID3v2_1_1Tag.html  The frames in this case are specific to ID3v2 tags; they don't exist in the `TagLib::Tag` base-class since that class is used for *all* tag formats.

Comment: Thanks! Will it work regardless if the tags are id3v2.3 or id3v2.4.?  What happens if the file only contains ID3v1 tags?