# TagLib: write string to RemixedBy field

Tags: c#, taglib, id3

I'm writing a simple program in C# to tidy up the song information presented by Traktor. As far as I know Traktor gets this data from the ID3-tags.

The problem now is that I don't know how to address the "Remixed By/ Modified By" field through TagLib. When I check the possibilities of an TagLib instance (track.Tag.[options]), no suitable option is present.

I've been successful as far as title and artist are concerned. The information comes from the filename. Here is the code that does that:

```
        TagLib.File track = TagLib.File.Create(selectedSongFullPath);
        TitleToBeChecked = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedSongFullPath);

        if (TitleToBeChecked.Contains("-"))
        {
            int hyphenIndex = TitleToBeChecked.IndexOf("-");
            string title = TitleToBeChecked.Substring(hyphenIndex + 1).Trim();
            string contributingArtists = TitleToBeChecked.Substring(0, hyphenIndex).Trim();
            track.Tag.Title = title;
            string[] contributingArtistsArray = {contributingArtists};
            track.Tag.Performers = contributingArtistsArray;
            track.Save();
        }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

According to the id3(v2) specification, information about Remixes belongs to the text information frame:

```
TPE4
The 'Interpreted, remixed, or otherwise modified by' frame contains more information about the people behind a remix and similar interpretations of another existing piece.
```

Source: http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0

Comment: Ty for having a look at it. I have been looking in that direction too, though I have no idea how to address/use/edit by using the frameid with TagLib.

Comment: Maybe the code (in C++) in this answer can give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628798/taglib-how-to-edit-album-artist/16630372